# FFMPEG and libavfilter

Tags: php, ffmpeg

With the currently installed ffmpeg I can't post watermark on converted videos. Can the reason for that be that I have not installed libavfilter library?

Currently # ffmpeg -v looks like:

```
FFmpeg version SVN-r20374, Copyright (c) 2000-2009 Fabrice Bellard, et al.
built on Oct 26 2009 22:47:01 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)
configuration: --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-version3 -   enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-libfaad --enable-gpl - -disable-mmx --enable-shared --enable-libfaac --enable-libvorbis
libavutil     50. 3. 0 / 50. 3. 0
libavcodec    52.37. 1 / 52.37. 1
libavformat   52.39. 2 / 52.39. 2
libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
```

As you can see I'm missing libavfilter? How can I add that library to FFMPEG and successfully add watermark on videos?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you please provide the command you are using to call ffmpeg, covert the video, add the watermark etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are missing `libavfilter`, try installing it using the following:

```
cd /
svn checkout svn://svn.ffmpeg.org/soc/libavfilter
cd libavfilter
./checkout.sh
```

You will then have to enable it in ffmpeg:

```
./configure --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf
make
```

Verify it has worked using:

```
ffmpeg -filters
```

In my experience, installing extensions and codecs after ffmpeg has already been installed does not always work. If it doesn't work, I recommend removing ffmpeg and starting over.

Comment: @Christopher- This is what I get when I try to install libavfilter:
Checked out revision 32676.
patching ffmpeg
patch: **** Can't create file tmp/po7ip7Co : No such file or directory
patch: **** Can't create file tmp/poiUXNkr : No such file or directory
patch: **** Can't create file tmp/poxFhQEr : No such file or directory
copying files to libavfilter

Comment: I did have a similar problem once. I got round it by creating those directories manually and letting it install the various components.

Answer (score 0):

To add watermark on videos, you can try this example to top left corner. It uses videofilter vf [link](http://www.idude.net/index.php/how-to-watermark-a-video-using-ffmpeg/)

```
ffmpeg –i inputvideo.avi -vf "movie=watermarklogo.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=10:10 [out]" outputvideo.flv
```